# Is the move constructor called after invoking a conversion function?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, language-lawyer, c++17

Consider this example:

```
struct T { };

struct S {
    operator T();
};

S s;
T t = s;
```

[dcl.init] will take us to [over.match.copy] which will find the conversion function `operator T()`. But are we done at that point, or do we have to invoke `T(T&& rhs)`, binding `rhs` to the return of `operator T()` via [dcl.init.ref]? Are there any differences with regards to the answer to this question between C++11 and C++1z?

Comment: I believe that copy-initialization requires that there be an accessible copy constructor (for `T`), but will use the move constructor if available (or elide the copy altogether, depending on the `operator T()` implementation it may be able to apply NRVO).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This falls under [[dcl.init]/17.6.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#17.6.3), which is pretty clear about what happens after overload resolution selects the conversion function:

> The function selected is called with the initializer expression as its
>   argument; if the function is a constructor, the call is a prvalue of
>   the cv-unqualified version of the destination type whose result object
>   is initialized by the constructor. The call is used to
>   direct-initialize, according to the rules above, the object that is
>   the destination of the copy-initialization.

In your case this in turn recurses into  [[dcl.init]/17.6.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#17.6.1):

> If the initializer expression is a prvalue and the cv-unqualified
>   version of the source type is the same class as the class of the
>   destination, the initializer expression is used to initialize the
>   destination object.

---

In C++11 the second step does invoke a move constructor, since it doesn't have the bullet corresponding to C++17's 17.6.1. Instead [you do the direct-initialization/overload resolution dance again](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init#16.6.1):

> If the initialization is direct-initialization, [...], constructors are 
>   considered. The applicable constructors
>   are enumerated ([over.match.ctor]), and the best one is chosen through
>   overload resolution ([over.match]). The constructor so selected is
>   called to initialize the object, with the initializer expression or
>   expression-list as its argument(s). If no constructor applies, or the
>   overload resolution is ambiguous, the initialization is ill-formed.

This move can (and in practice will) be elided; see [[class.copy]/31](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.copy#31.3).

---

The more interesting case is actually

```
T t(s);
```

which under the C++17 wording is actually *required* to call a move constructor, because it uses the direct-initialization rule and does overload resolution on `T`'s constructors. That selects `T`'s move constructor and calls it to initialize `t`, converting `s` to a `T` prvalue that is materialized into a temporary and bound to the parameter of the move constructor. The 17.6.1 bullet is simply not reachable in the process, and the bullet in C++11's [class.copy]/31 (now [[class.copy.elision]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.copy.elision#1)) that permitted elision in this scenario was removed in C++17.

This is most likely a defect.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the last part? Why doesn't 17.6.1 apply the same way in the two cases?

Comment: @Barry Elaborated.

Comment: Thank you very much. I, for one, am looking forward to the paper proposing simplifying initialization...

Comment: @Barry Aren't we all. Considering there is already multiple posts on initialization here on SO, some even included in C++ FAQ, which IMO is *way* too much

Comment: Would C++11 actually allow elision here? Since the initialization is from a `S` object to a `T` object, and from a `T` prvalue object to a `T &&` reference, but never from a `T` prvalue object to a `T` object, I don't see yet how C++11 allowed the move to be elided either.

Comment: Note that "copy" and "move" is defined as "A class object can be copied or moved in two ways: by initialization ([class.ctor], [dcl.init]), including for function argument passing ([expr.call]) and for function value return; and by assignment. ". So to allow elision in C++11, you would have to have a move of a T (prvalue temporary) object to another T object, which I don't see happening here.

Comment: Therefore, strictly speaking, there is no move of a T object to another T object, but just an invocation of a move constructor of T with a T object as argument (kindof, as the result of the user defined conversion sequence on `s`). That may seem like hairsplitting, but appears to have significant effects.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Your "hairsplitting" reading disagrees with every implementer AFAICS, which strongly suggests that it's not the intended reading :)